# Piwik tracking script working on all browsers except IE8 and below

Tags: javascript, matomo

I have a tracking script on an E-commerce site receipt page. The script simply fetches the product information from the DOM and tracks it using the Piwik E-commerce tracking functions. This works fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer 8 and below. I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with the script for weeks. I've tested it locally on a dummy receipt page and it works fine in IE, but it's not tracking any sales for IE 5-8 on the live page.

The tracking script is inserted to the receipt page via an OpenTag tag and so is piwik.js, but I'm using the asynchronous tracker so that shouldn't be an issue, as all browsers except IE confirms.

Here is the code that is injected via OpenTag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Closure that supports jQuery
    (function($) {
        // Function for removing everything from a string except numbers and
        // returning that number as an integer
        var num = function(text) {
            return parseInt(text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
        };

        // Trims whitespace from before and after a string. "  hello  " => "hello"
        var trim = function(text) {
            return text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        };

        // Run on document ready
        $(function() {

            // Ready a reference to Piwik async queue
            _paq = _paq || [];

            // Referansenummeret
            var order_id = num(
                $('span#ctl00_CPHCnt_McInPlaceEdYourRefNbr_McInPlaceEdYourRefNbr')
                .closest('p').text()
            );

            // Hent verdien som ligger etter "Total:"
            // var total = num(
            //     $('span#ctl00_CPHCnt_HandlevognProdukListe1_McInPlaceEdTotInclAVT2_McInPlaceEdTotInclAVT2')
            //     .closest('tr').children('td:last-child').text()
            // );
            var total = 0;

            // Hent verdien som ligger etter "Sum:"
            var sub_total = num(
                $('span#ctl00_CPHCnt_HandlevognProdukListe1_McInPlaceEditorSum_McInPlaceEditorSum')
                .closest('tr').children('td:last-child').text()
            );

            // Hent verdien som ligger etter "Herav mva:"
            var mva = num(
                $('table.CartSummaryTable .TotalValue').closest('tr').next()
                .children('td:last-child').text()
            );

            // Hent verdien som ligger etter "Frakt inkl. evt. gebyr:"
            var shipping = num(
                $('span#ctl00_CPHCnt_HandlevognProdukListe1_McInPlaceEdFreightInclFee_McInPlaceEdFreightInclFee')
                .closest('tr').children('td:last-child').text()
            );

            // Cheat solution - the total doesn't have a 100% hitrate so just
            // add the sub_total and shipping together.
            total = sub_total + shipping;

            // Iterate over the product rows and extract the information
            $('table#ProductList tr.VerticalText').each(function(index, row) {
                var sku = trim($('td:first-child', row).text());
                var prod_name = trim($('div.ProduktDesc span', row).text());
                var categories = [];
                var price = num($('td:nth-child(5)', row).text());
                var quant = num($('td:nth-child(4)', row).text());

                // Extrapolate categories from the product link URL
                var path = $('.ProduktDesc a', row).attr('href').split('/');
                for(var i = 2; i < path.length - 1; i++)
                {
                    categories.push(path[i]);
                }

                // Track this product
                _paq.push(['addEcommerceItem', sku, prod_name, categories, price, quant]);
            });

            // Track this order
            _paq.push(['trackEcommerceOrder', order_id, total, sub_total, mva, shipping, false]);
        });
    }(window.jQuery.noConflict(true)));
</script>
```

Asking on StackOverflow is my last resort, I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't tracking any sales for Internet Explorer 5-8.

I'll accept the first answer that leads me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out. It turns out OpenTag was transforming the URL "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" into "////ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" only in Internet Explorer. We solved it by figuring out the protocol using JavaScript instead.